# I have a multi valued field is "o_is_follow" it should returns single value only

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo7/select?q=*:*&fq=o_photo_id:2014077070 AND o_is_follow:20120&indent=true&wt=xml

<arr name="o_is_follow">
 <str>{14317</str>
 <str>19863</str>
 <str>20120}</str>
</arr>
```

o/p:-

```
o_is_follow

20120
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot. MultiValued field is stored as a single item and returned all at once.

You should look into using child records with join commands or perhaps highlighting to identify which part of the record had actually been found.

You also don't need to use **AND** in the **fq** filter, just use two **fq** params.